# Matriz compuesta ¿como imprimir dos matrices con espacio entre ellas?

Tags: java, matriz

¿como mostrar dos matrices compuesta con espacio entre si?
abajo dejo de una foto de como se me imprimi. Logro hacer la matriz compuesta, pero cuando la imprimo sale toda junta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class MatrizCompuesta {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[][] matriz = new int[4][4]; 
            Random aleatorio = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    matriz[i][j] = aleatorio.nextInt(10); 
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    System.out.print("[" + matriz[i][j] + "]");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    System.out.print("[" + matriz[j][i] + "]");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cuando dices con espacio entre sí. ¿A que te refieres exactamente? ¿Que entre la primera y segunda matriz que realizas con los ciclos for se encuentre un espacio?

Comment: lo que quiero decir es que a la hora de imprimirse, se vea con un espacio entre la matriz original y la compuesta

Comment: Pues creo que es suficiente añadiendo un `System.out.println("");` entre el segundo ciclo for (Matriz original) y el tercer ciclo for (Matriz compuesta).

Comment: @DiegoDscz pon una imagen con el resultado que esperas

Comment: Al final fue tu solución la acertada. Mil gracias

Comment: Al final me sirvio tu respuesta, pero no se como agregarte puntos. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te sirva imprimirlo así:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    String aux = ", ";
    System.out.print( "[ " );
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if( j == 3 ) {
            aux = " ]\n";
        }
        System.out.print( matriz[i][j] + aux );
    }
}
```